# Accidently xkill remote ubuntu server now cannot connect

Tags: server, remote-desktop, vnc, vncviewer, xkill

I accidently xkill a ubuntu desktop on a server that is hosted remotely, after I did that I got kicked off the VNC Viewer. Now I'm getting a VNC message that "The connection was refused by the host computer". I can't get physical access to this server. What can I do?

Comment: Does it have some sort of timer that I can go on it eventually?

Comment: can you get in through SSH? if so reboot it

Comment: Do you have other means to connect to the server? If not, there's nothing you can do without physical access.